# Is it possible to add same method to a button click after removing it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

After removing target from button click by this code:

```
 [answer1 removeTarget:self action:@selector(answerSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

can it will be possible to add same method to same button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[answer1 addTarget:self action:@selector(answerSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with adding a method to a button after it has been removed.